# Excel: Sum of largest numbers

Tags: excel

Excel offers the function LARGE, and when combined with SUM, it allows summing up the top N largest numbers. This works fine for cases where the area from which these numbers are drawn is continuous, for example with this examlple:

```
SUM(LARGE(A1:A10),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
```

This would extract the top 7 largest numbers from an area of 10 cells (that are contingious). How do I do that if I have only every second cell, i.e. I want to use A1, A3, A5, ... ?

Here the data in the spreadsheet:

```
A     B     C      D    E

3.5   80   2.5    90    5.5
```

I want to find the largest number from 3.5, 2.5, 5.5 etc... The ONLY condition that exists between neighbour numbers (e.g. A and B) is that B is always larger than the other. The reason why I need to keep both numbers is purely for reasons of completeness.

In short: How do I use the LARGE function with a set distributed individual cells?

Answer (score 2):

Try this formula:

```
=SUM(LARGE(INDEX((MOD(COLUMN($A$1:$E$1),2)=1)*$A$1:$E$1,),{1,2,3}))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]